# How to do insert method on Word Frequency counter using linked list

Tags: java, linked-list, frequency, cpu-word

```
public class Frequency<E extends Comparable> implements Iterable<E>{
    private Node first;
    private int N;
    Frequency(){
        N = 0;
        first = null;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return new ListIterator();
    }
    /**
     * 
     * List iterator
     *
     */
    private class ListIterator implements Iterator<E>{
        private Node current;
        private int index ;
        ListIterator(){
            current = first;
            index = 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return current != null;
        }


        public E next() {
            if(!hasNext()){
                return null;
            }
            E word = current.key;
            int count = current.count;
            String r = "("+word + "," + Integer.toString(count)+")";
            current = current.next;
            return (E)r;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {

        } 
        public int compareTo(Frequency<E>.Node first) {
                return next.compareTo(first);
        }
    }
    }
    /**
     * 
     * Node class
     *
     */
    private class Node {
        private E key;
        private int count;
        private Node next;
        Node(E item){
            key = item;
            count = 1;
            next = null;
        }
        @Override 
        public String toString(){
            return "("+key +","+count+")";
        }
    }
    /*
     * Inserts a word into the linked list. If the word exists, increment the 
     * count by 1. 
     */
    public void insert(E word){
        if(word.equals("")){
            return;
        }
        Node current=first;
    Node temp=null;
    while(current != null){
        if(current.key.equals(word)){
            current.count++;
            temp=current;
        }
        current=current.next;   
    }
    while(temp !=null && temp.next != null){
        if(temp.count>first.count){
            temp=first.next;
            first.next=temp.next;
            temp.next=first;
            first=temp;
        }
    }
    while(temp !=null && temp.next != null){
        if(temp.count==first.count){
            if(temp.compareTo(first)<0){
                temp=first.next;
                first.next=temp.next;
                temp.next=first;
                first=temp;     
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to sort the words in their frequency order from most frequent word to the least frequent. If two words have the same frequency they are sorted in alphabetical order. I'm not sure how to do the insert method that combines all the things I have to do. I've made attempts to do the add count part and the frequency ordering part, and I have no idea how to sort the same frequencies alphabetically. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you strictly tied to using a linked list? Rather than do everything in one method, try breaking the problem down. Start by sorting your list, Java already has a sweet method for this `Collections.sort(myList)`

Comment: I can't use collection.sort and we have to use only one method. We could use private helper methods though.

Comment: do you have to use a linked-list? It's worth mentioning that iterating over it is much slower, and any sorting method you implement is likely to be slower than javas native one, so speed probably matters. `ArrayList` also has a `ListIterator`.

Comment: Its mostly singly linked list practice so I have to use it. All the steps are not too confusing but I'm not sure how to put it all together. Especially how to sort the same frequency nodes alphabetically.

Comment: if all you need is the output, just sort your `Nodes` by frequency. Then loop over them and anytime you come across multiple nodes with the same frequency, put them all in a Collection together, then pass that Collection to a helper method that will sort them alphabetically and return a sorted Sub-Collection.

Comment: I get what your saying, but I'm pretty new to java and I don't really know how to do some of these steps. Sorry if I'm being difficult but I've never really done some of these things.

Comment: I've posted a logical solution to sort a subset of equivalent frequency nodes, if there are any other particular pieces you are having trouble with, please be clear what they are.